# Oracle Schema designer

Tags: database, oracle10g

I don't know the real name of that application but what i want to do is so simple, i have an oracle database with more than 50 tables. I want to get their names also their field names, so i thought that it would be nice to use a designer or something like mssql has. Then i can get the field names and table names easily. How can i do that?

Thanks for the help,
Mehmet Şerif Tozlu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "getting table and field names" you mean, inside a program, you need to use Oracle's METADATA through any METADATA API you feel more comfortable with: JDBC, ADO.NET, ODBC, or even performing queries against METADATA tables (user_tables, all_tables, etc).

If by "getting table and field names" you mean a visual tool to inspect them, there are a lot of them.

1. [PL/SQL developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) (My Favorite, by far: fast, useful. Unfortunately, runs only on Windows)
2. [Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/)
3. [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) (Oracle's java based free programming tool)
4. [Enterprise Manager](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/enterprise-manager/index.html) (Oracle's java based administering tool)
5. ...

Hope it helps.

Comment: i mean a visual tool and i use pl/sql for queries but i want to see those 50 or more tables in one screen with their relationships.. then i can see what are the table and field names..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outputting all 50 tables and all columns all at once, what you may want to do is to generate several diagrams, each containing tables for a functional part of your system. In a hypothetical system, this could be "client and accounts", "bank transactions", and so on. Some tables may appear in multiple diagrams. Not all columns may need to be outputted, especially if they do not belong to a particular functional area of your system.

You can use [SchemaCrawler for Oracle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemacrawler/files/SchemaCrawler%20-%20Oracle/). [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) allows you to search for and only output tables and columns that match a regular expression, as well as to generate database diagrams, with the help of GraphViz. It also find implied relationships between tables if the schema uses a naming convention.